# How to install GCC on Windows 10 for use in VS2017

Tags: c#, c++, gcc, windows-10

In attempting to build this solution:

https://github.com/garuma/PiHueSphinx

I am seeing this in the output window:

```
gcc -Wall -ggdb -shared -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sphinxbase -I/usr/local/include/pocketsphinx -L/usr/local/lib -lpocketsphinx -lsphinxad -lsphinxbase -o \libsphinx_hue_detection.so sphinx_hue_detection.c
```

I am building on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

This post does not show how to get GCC installed or working on Windows:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/

How can I get GCC installed and working from a .csproj file (as done in the above project)?

Comment: You can get the [MinGW64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) implementation of GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install it using [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) details on how to install cygwin in windows is given in this article. http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/